# How to properly store data in firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine

I want to save a record for a Unity project and figure out how player data is stored on the server.
I was advised to use Firebase.
As a result, I decided that I would use Anonymous authentication and store a Dictionary in the database with the PlayerId key and the Record value.
Did I choose the right solution?
Thank you!

Comment: Opinion question, outside the website proposal.

Answer (score 0):

You can use realtime database in Firebase.

You can get needed information here - [firebase database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database)